# Return data between first and fifth backslash

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need some regex that will return the value between first and fifth backslash has highlighted below in bold:

dataCapture/**22E6F953EA6D445C8FB20E9D29A977D7/6.20.0-3c1e4b0c459eb93e43eb64fed7447a41fb4d4029/uuid_2b896c17-eb5c-4fd1-ae44-78dcda6c8ee9/36**/3D1C3A58A039103375D320E524500A74

So far I've only been able to come up with regex that returns data up till the first backslash:

```
\/dataCapture\/(.+?)\/
```

How do I extend the above to include data up to the fifth backslash?

Comment: I'm using a regex extractor in JMeter. I'll add the JMeter tag

Comment: @MateenUlhaq No, my regex only returns 22E6F953EA6D445C8FB20E9D29A977D7

Comment: `^dataCapture/(.+)/[^/]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the cleanest but that makes the job done:

```js
const regex = /dataCapture\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+\/[0-9]+)\/.*/;

const value = "dataCapture/22E6F953EA6D445C8FB20E9D29A977D7/6.20.0-3c1e4b0c459eb93e43eb64fed7447a41fb4d4029/uuid_2b896c17-eb5c-4fd1-ae44-78dcda6c8ee9/36/3D1C3A58A039103375D320E524500A74";

console.log(value.match(regex)[1]); // => 22E6F953EA6D445C8FB20E9D29A977D7/6.20.0-3c1e4b0c459eb93e43eb64fed7447a41fb4d4029/uuid_2b896c17-eb5c-4fd1-ae44-78dcda6c8ee9/36
```

Comment: Giving you the tick as your's is the only one that worked in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this regex pattern, you have to use the following code:

`^\/dataCapture\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/`

You can test this regex in [this site](https://regex101.com).

Comment: Nice! However I think we want to capture all the string between 1st and 5th slashes. I like how simpler your solution would be though

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with JMeter, but I understand it uses a slight variant of Perl5's regex engine, so I expect matching the following regular expression will extract the string of interest.

```
(?<=^dataCapture\/)(?:[^\/]*\/){3}[^\/]*(?=\/)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/C1dS3a/3/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=             : begin positive lookbehind
  ^              : match beginning of string
  dataCapture\/  : match 'dataCapture\/
)                : end positive lookbehind 
(?:[^\/]*\/)     : match 0+ charsother than '/', followed by '/', in
                   a non-capture group
{3}              : execute the non-capture group 3 times
[^\/]*           : match 0+ chars other than '/'
(?=\/)           : positive lookahead asserts that the next char is '/'
```